# Conditional executing an ajax call in rxjs

Tags: rxjs, reactivex, redux-observable

I'm starting with learning how to use RxJS and I have implemented an epic with a conditional Ajax call like this:

```
export default (action$, store) =>
  action$.ofType(GET_USERS_BY_ID)
    .mergeMap((action) => {
      const userIdList = action.userIdList;

      let observable;
      if (userIdList.length > 0) {
        observable = ajax.get('api/user', { userIdList });
      } else {
        observable = Observable.of({
          response: {}
        });
      }

      return observable
        .mergeMap((payload) => {
          doSomething1(payload);
          doSomething2(payload);
        });
    });
```

Is this the right way to do it, or are there some operators that simplify this?

Comment: This will emit `doSomething1` and `doSomething2` with an empty response if the `userIdlList.length == 0` which seems odd. @glendaviesnz's answer seems more inline of what'd I'd expect to see, can you clarify why it's not?

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to process actions where the userIdList has items in it, then you can filter them before making the ajax call, eg.

```
export default (action$, store) =>
 action$.ofType(GET_USERS_BY_ID)
.filter(action => userIdList.length > 0)
.mergeMap((action) => {
  const userIdList = action.userIdList;

  return ajax.get('api/user', { userIdList })
    .mergeMap((payload) => {
      doSomething1(payload);
      doSomething2(payload);
    });
});
```

Comment: But then the functions `doSomething1(payload); doSomething2(payload);` are not executed for an empty list.

Comment: That is true - if the empty state is important then this approach does not apply.